# Excel Save fails in Windows 7

Tags: excel-2007

I have created an application to interact with Excel in C#.net
The API to save the Excel

```
 Excel._Workbook m_oWorkBook;  
 m_oWorkBook.Save();
```

Throws up a File Saveas MessageBox though the workbook was already saved in a given name.

Note:
  This happens only in Windows 7 & only when another Workbook was already opened.

Any clues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much (if anything at all) about CSharp's Excel API, but seeing as nobody else has tried to answer this question yet I can't say you have any better options. : )

Having perused some documentation, I have found that the Excel._Workbook.SaveAs() method allows you to specify a filename, among other things.  If it is true that the Save() method is only opening the SaveAs dialog on Win7, it could very well just be a bug in Win7.  I would suggest, to temporarily avoid this bug, you should use the SaveAs() method instead of Save().  All parameters are optional and *filename* is the first one, so you could hypothetically just pass it the filename of the current file and that *should* achieve the same functionality as is intended from Save().

*IF* this is a bug in Windows 7, I think this would be the best/least painful way to get around it.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tyler,
  I have already tried SaveAs API Instead of Save API with all the relevant parameters still it pops up the dialog. More importantly it happens When I try to create a new Excel file in a new Instance when an excel file is already opened.

THIS PROGRAM WORKS FINE IN WIN VISTA & XP.

It also throws an exception saying "Remote Procedure call" failed.

Comment: Ah, sorry I couldn't have been more help on the Save/SaveAs issue.

This is a very odd problem, though, as it works fine in Vista.  I fully expect it must be some kind of bug in the Win7 API.  Are you making any Remote Procedure calls?  If not, I find it kind of scary that Microsoft would feel the need to put RPC into their *Excel* API...